# How to force QGIS 3.6.1 create raster's pyramids (overviews) when I drag&drop them in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, image-pyramids

There is a [build-overviews-pyramids tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#build-overviews-pyramids) to create pyramids but I want to create them automatically when I add (drag & drop) raster layer into QGIS interface.

I have found parameters that is looking very similar to what I need but perhaps it only create pyramids when I use GDAL tools.

[image]

Comment: The settings in the dialog are right but what you miss is a button "Create overviews automatically without asking". Consider making a feature request.

Comment: @user30184 I found the same request: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no such option in QGIS, and this function has already been requested:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13637